How to create, add and remove liquidity using @raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2?
I’m currently working with @raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2 and trying to figure out how to create, add, and remove liquidity on the Raydium platform. Could anyone provide a code example or a step-by-step guide on how to perform these actions? I’d like to understand the process from the ground up, including interacting with the smart contract to add tokens to a liquidity pool and how to remove liquidity when necessary.
Thanks in advance!

You can check this repo: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo/tree/master/src/amm
Start with the file createMarket.ts, createAmmPool.ts, ... Before performing all steps, you need to create your own dummy tokens for testing.
You can read this tutorial: https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/updates/archive/creating-an-openbook-amm-pool
After that, try using the repository link above.
